# Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview

I have the following method in my UITableViewController subclass:

```
-(void)populateDataStorage{

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FakeData" ofType:@"plist"];

if(path){
    NSArray *plistData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [plistData objectEnumerator];

    NSArray *personResults;

    Photo *photo;
    Person *person;

    id currItem = [enumerator nextObject];

    while (currItem != nil) {
        photo = (Photo *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext: [[FlickrFetcher sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];

        photo.name = [currItem objectForKey:@"name"];
        photo.path = [currItem objectForKey:@"path"];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", [currItem objectForKey:@"user"]];

        personResults = [[FlickrFetcher sharedInstance] fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:@"Person" withPredicate:predicate];

        if ([personResults count] > 0) {
            person = [personResults objectAtIndex:0];
        } 
        else {
            person = (Person *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:[[FlickrFetcher sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];
            person.name = [currItem objectForKey:@"user"];
        }

        photo.person = person;
        [person addPhotosObject:photo];

        NSLog(@"Photo %@ added for user %@", photo.name, person.name);

        currItem = [enumerator nextObject];
    }

    [plistData release];
}
```

}

And I call it in my apps didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in my AppDelegate, the method is also in the same AppDelegate, when it's called I get the error it says there when debugging, if I don't debug the line it will run the method and load with no problem. If I don't debug at all it will not call the method.

EDIT: Changed the code according to the answer the problem still remains the same, if I just run nothing happens but when debugging I get the error. When I debug the whole method no error is shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `NSLog` is trying to access the `name` property of your `person` variable.  However, when you declared your `person` variable, you didn't initialize it, so it points to garbage.  You only give it a valid value in your `else` clause, so sometimes your NSLog is accessing an uninitialized object.

Comment: I modified the code and updated my post, the problem persists

Comment: How did you modify the code?  Can you add the updated code to your post?

Comment: What I did was set the person object in both cases of the if statement, to correct what you said, that way when I access it's name property it's always set to something